# Create a JSON file and parse it in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, game-development

I'm trying to create a JSON file that holds the conversations between characters in a game. In each chapter of the game I want to load/parse the JSON file and assign the conversations to the identified characters.
I've created an Enum for characters and a Struct for conversations as following:

```
enum Speaker: String {   
    case Protagonist 
    case CharacterA 
    case CharacterB
    case CharacterC 
}

struct Dialogue {
    var speaker: Speaker
    var messages = [String]()
}
```

and the JSON file as following:

```
{
  "chapter":  [
    {
    "speaker": "Character A",   
    "conversation": [
           {
            "speaker": "Character A",
            "diagloue": "Hello stranger, what brought you here?"
            },
           {
            "speaker": "protagonist",
            "diagloue": "I'm here to look for some guy."
           },
          {
            "speaker": "Character A",
            "diagloue": "I've lived here all my life. Maybe I can help you."
          }
           
        ]
    },
    
    {
    "speaker": "Character B",
    "conversation": [
            {
            "speaker": "protagonist",
            "diagloue": "Why is the gate closed?"
            },
           {
            "speaker": "Character B",
            "diagloue": "No one is allowed to leave town until further notice."
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

As this is my very first attempt with JSON, I've no idea if I'm doing it right. Will the JSON file I put together give me what I needed? If not, how should I structure my JSON file?
One last questions, how do I parse the file in Swift 5? My understanding is to create a Struct that will hold the data. Something like below?

```
struct Chapter: Decodable {
    let chapter: [Conversation]

}
struct Conversation: Decodable {
    let speaker: String
    let conversation: [Dialogue]
}

struct Dialogue: Decodable {
    let speaker: String
    let diagloue: String
}

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "conversation", ofType: "json")
let jsonData = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
let conversation = try JSONDecoder().decode(Chapter.self, from: jsonData as! Data)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Nothing matches, you should do some more reading. The Apple SwiftUI tutorial dealing with User input has a full example within. There is also a website called QuickType.io you can test your JSON there

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. I went back and done some more research and revised my code. it seems that I can now parse it. However, I still need to work on restructuring my JSON file as it doesn't give me all the info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to parse a JSON file in Swift 5:

```swift
import Foundation

// Define a struct to represent your JSON data structure
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

// Read the JSON file and parse its contents
func parseJSONFromFile() {
    // Get the file URL of the JSON file
    guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") else {
        print("JSON file not found.")
        return
    }
    
    do {
        // Read the file contents into a Data object
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        
        // Parse the JSON data into Swift objects
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let person = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: jsonData)
        
        // Access the parsed data
        print("Name: \(person.name)")
        print("Age: \(person.age)")
    } catch {
        print("JSON parsing error: \(error)")
    }
}

// Call the function to parse the JSON file
parseJSONFromFile()
```

And here's an example of how to write data to a JSON file:

```swift
import Foundation

// Define a struct to represent your data structure
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

// Write data to a JSON file
func writeDataToJSONFile() {
    // Create an instance of your data structure
    let person = Person(name: "John Doe", age: 30)
    
    do {
        // Encode the data structure to JSON data
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(person)
        
        // Get the file URL where you want to save the JSON file
        guard let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("data.json") else {
            print("Error creating file URL.")
            return
        }
        
        // Write the JSON data to the file
        try jsonData.write(to: fileURL)
        
        print("JSON data written to file: \(fileURL.absoluteString)")
    } catch {
        print("Error writing JSON data: \(error)")
    }
}

// Call the function to write data to the JSON file
writeDataToJSONFile()
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample codes.